# LINQ collection - Select all fields(columns) of the object except one field (column)

Tags: c#, linq

I am not looking for SQL Statements but instead linq solution.

The model / object contains a lot fields and selecting each field name in linq select is tedious.

The exact problem and solution is provided here

https://terryaney.wordpress.com/2013/02/27/use-selectexcept-when-you-are-too-lazy-to-type/

However, the extension method given above solution does not work.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Returns all fields/properties from <paramref name="source"/> except for the field(s)/property(ies) listed in the selector expression.
    /// </summary>
    public static IQueryable SelectExcept<TSource, TResult>( this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> selector )
    {
        var newExpression = selector.Body as NewExpression;

        var excludeProperties = newExpression != null
                ? newExpression.Members.Select( m => m.Name )
                : new[] { ( (MemberExpression)selector.Body ).Member.Name };
        
        var sourceType = typeof( TSource );
        var allowedSelectTypes = new Type[] { typeof( string ), typeof( ValueType ), typeof( XElement ) };
        var sourceProperties = sourceType.GetProperties( BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance ).Where( p => allowedSelectTypes.Any( t => t.IsAssignableFrom( ( (PropertyInfo)p ).PropertyType ) ) ).Select( p => ( (MemberInfo)p ).Name );
        var sourceFields = sourceType.GetFields( BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance ).Where( f => allowedSelectTypes.Any( t => t.IsAssignableFrom( ( (FieldInfo)f ).FieldType ) ) ).Select( f => ( (MemberInfo)f ).Name );

        var selectFields = sourceProperties.Concat( sourceFields ).Where( p => !excludeProperties.Contains( p ) ).ToArray();

        var dynamicSelect = 
                string.Format( "new( {0} )",
                        string.Join( ", ", selectFields ) );

        return selectFields.Count() > 0
            ? source.AsQueryable().Select( dynamicSelect )
            : Enumerable.Empty<TSource>().AsQueryable<TSource>();
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by *it does not work*? Do you get an exception, a wrong results, etc.?

Comment: Yes, I get exception.  When I tried to use

objects.SelectExcept(p => new { p.email, p.name});

or 

objectCollection.SelectExcept(p=>p.email)

I get below exception
The type initializer for 'System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser' threw an exception.

Comment: Maybe for you it is ok to select `x => new TSource { Field1 = x.Field1, Field2 = x.Field2 }`? In this case we can do that without DynamicLINQ.